# Rerender the pageblocksection for certain fields in the same section

Tags: visualforce, rerender, apexpage

I have a `VF Page`, where I want to make certain fields as a required field based on picklist value. all the fields are in the same `Pageblock section.`

But here the issue is when I am changing the picklist value entire `pageblock` section is getting refreshed and all the values except picklist value are getting reset.

is there anyway so that I can retain the `Amount__c` field value after changing the picklist value.

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:form> 
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageblocksection id="pbSection">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Source" />
                    <apex:actionRegion>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Lead_Source__c}">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="pbSection" />
                        </apex:inputField>
                    </apecx:actionRegion>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Country__c}" required="{if(opp.Lead_Source__c='Country', true, false)}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!opp.State__c}" required="{if(opp.Lead_Source__c='State', true, false)}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Amount}" />
            </apex:pageblocksection>        
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
```

Comment: Do you have `immediate="true"` in your `actionsupport`?  I'd expect this to choke on the required fields without it, and with it you're going to see the behavior you are talking about.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian : No I don't have any immediate attribute in action support

Comment: But immediate=true is for to skip the validation rule for that field. My issue is here to retain the Amount__c field value once I am changing the picklist value.

Because once I am changing the picklist value, entire pageblock section gets reloaded and Amount__c value gets blank.

Comment: Best correct `önchange` to be `onchange`.

Comment: @KeithC : That's the typo. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use action function as below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:pageMessages id="messages"></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:form> 
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageblocksection id="pbSection">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Source" />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Lead_Source__c}" onchange="handleLeadSourceChange(this.value);">                         
                        </apex:inputField>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Lead_Source__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Country__c}" required="{!if(Opportunity.Lead_Source__c='Country', true, false) }" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.State__c}" required="{!if(Opportunity.Lead_Source__c='State', true, false)}" />
                <apex:inputField styleClass="OppAmount" value="{!Opportunity.Amount}" />
            </apex:pageblocksection>        
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!null}" name="leadSourceChange" rerender="pbSection,messages">
                <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!Opportunity.Lead_Source__c}" value="" />
                <apex:param name="secondParam" assignTo="{!Opportunity.Amount}" value="" />
            </apex:actionFunction>
        </apex:actionRegion>
        <script>
               function handleLeadSourceChange( leadSource){
                    leadSourceChange(leadSource,jQuery('.OppAmount').val());
               }
        </script> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You can checkout output below:

[image]